# Error_reporing не работает (Web-hosting)

Tags: php, веб-сервер, хостинг

Не работает `error_reporting(E_ALL);` на моем сайте, хотя все написано правильно. Что делать? У меня веб-хостинг/веб-сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Все, что нужно сделать - добавить `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` перед `error_reporting(E_ALL);` и тогда должно все заработать.